# How do you remove the Border in CKEDITOR?

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I am currently attempting to use CKEDITOR in a web app I am creating, I am using the inline editor that I activate just by calling `CKEDITOR.inline('editor')` and I have modified the colour of the inline editor to suit my application by modifying the config.js and adding `config.uiColor = '#ededed'`

However no matter what I try I can't seem to get rid of the border around the inline editor (as pictured below). There doesn't seem to be a config option for it. Has anyone had any experience with removing the border around the inline editor?

[image: Inline Editor Border]

As a sidenote, does anyone know why the CKEDITOR Hex->RGB conversion seems to be a little broken?

The actual hex colour that I wanted the editor to be was `#f3f3f3` but when CKEDITOR was loaded this was translated to an RGB of `247, 247, 247` when it should actually be `243, 243, 243`. Using `#ededed` produces an RGB of `243, 243, 243` in CKEDITOR even though it should be `237, 237, 237`.

Answer (score 0):

I used inspect mode from ckeditor.com. The border of the editor module can be removed by commenting out the following 'cke_chrome' class in editor.css located in the following folder (http://s1.ckeditor.com/themes/ckeditor4/vendor/ckeditor/4.6.2/skins/moono-lisa/editor.css?t=H0CI)

```
.cke_chrome {
    display: block;
    /* border: 1px solid #d1d1d1; */
    padding: 0;
}
```

NOTE: I was browsing from Chrome, so I assume that there might be a few other css entries in this editor.css file

If this doesn't help to get you started, maybe this article will help [Adding Custom Styles and Classes to your WYSIWYG](http://www.mediacurrent.com/blog/adding-custom-styles-ckeditor-wysiwyg)